# Rails Custom Routes Changes Assets Paths Resulting In 404 For Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-routing

I'm trying to customize my routes like this:
`get 'lcd-buyback/lot/:id' => 'lcd_buyback#lot_view'`

I originally had it like this: `get 'lcd_buyback/lot_view' => 'lcd_buyback#lot_view'`

The issue is that when I use the custom route, I get a 404 for my assets.

Here is the Request URL that gives 404: `http://localhost:3000/lcd-buyback/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Here is the Request URL that doesn't: `http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

As you can see, the custom route adds the `lcd-buyback` path I specified, to the assets Request URL.

How can I successfully access my assets when I customize routes? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets are called from your layout file with the corresponding tag. Make sure your **lcd_buyback** controller is using the right layout file.

In **app/views/application.html.erb** you will find:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

In **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css** you will find the file and all the other stylesheets it imports, as this example:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require tree .
```

On the first url you are missing **/lot** in order to match the new route.

Please provide more information about your controller and routes file.

Comment: Working on getting content for update now. You suggest `/lot` is missing from Request URL, so I tested with 'Edit and Resend' option in inspect element. This is the error I receive: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/lcd-buyback/lot/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"):` I even tried adding the ID but still get 404. Also, why would the Request URL show `lcd-buyback/lot` if it does not show the controller or action path when using rails default routes? Is it specific to custom routes?

Comment: Went into application.html.erb layout and found it was calling assets with standard html, not rails generated html. More specifically it was using `../rest_of_path` to access which is obviously why it was breaking. Replacing with `stylesheet_link_tag` and removing `..` fixed it. I hadn't touched the layout, so I assumed it was being called correctly, and felt there was some level of abstraction due to custom routes that I didn't understand, and hadn't implemented. Thanks for the direction to my application.html.erb file. I'll be sure to better check where and how I call things in the future.